# Build in Linux deploy to windows

Tags: .net, mono, xbuild

Build agent running on linux ( ubunto ).
I have used xbuild to build the .net standard project. But I'm going to deploy my application in windows. 
To achieve this I need to build the binaries for windows. 
when I used xbuild in linux it create binaries for linux. but I need binaries for windows.

Comment: CIL-based assemblies are cross-platform compatible, you can "just" copy them (of course any "native" shared libraries (.so, .dylib, .dll (native) would have to be cross-compiled). BTW: `xbuild` has been deprecated for a while now, `msbuild` is cross-platform and is the default for new versions of Mono.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get the lates mono docker container for Linux so I can create the build.
When I create the xbuild binaries. .dll file size are different to windows build. Any idea.
I hope new version of mono  can build  .net standard WCF project using msbuild